# I've updated my HDD to SSD but still have low W/R speed

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

My laptop has 2 SSD, one M.2 120GB (where i keep Windows) and a new installed Sata SSD 480GB (which replaced a HDD).

The problem is I have low write/read speed on the new SSD.
I've checked:

- AHCI is enabled on both disks
- drivers are updated
- disk cleanup

What else can i check/do ?
The speed on M.2 is normal.
The speed on 3.5"SSD is like the old HDD.

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: It's a cheap, probably cacheless SSD. Your results are slightly worse than I'd expect, but I wouldn't be surprised if that's just how these drives perform. These cheapest models are built with the cheapest components available. It's not unheard of for a single cheap SSD model to come with a few completely different sets of components throughout its market lifetime - whatever is cheaper to manufacture at a moment. This causes benchmarks to be all over the place too.

Comment: Is there any way to test if it's cacheless? Tnx for your response.

Comment: There's a heuristic to check it without dismantling the device, but I don't know the details. It's probably googlable. Broadly speaking the disk will behave slightly differently under certain loads. The certain way is to disassemble the disk and check if there's a cache chip on the logic board.